# Neural Network Outputs Are Not Changing Very Much

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, encog

I have 20 output neurons on a feed-forward neural  network, for which I have *already* tried varying the number of hidden layers and number of neurons per hidden layer.  When testing, I've noticed that while the outputs are not always exactly the same, they vary from test case to case very little, especially in respect to one another.  It seems to be outputting *nearly* (within 0.0005 depending on the initial weights) the same output on every test case; the one that is the highest is always the highest.  Is there a reason for this?

Note: I'm using a feed-forward neural network, with resilient and common backpropagation, separating training/validation/testing and shuffling in between training sets.

UPDATE: I'm using the network to categorize patterns from 4 inputs into one of twenty output possibilities. I have 5000 training sets, 800 validation sets, and 1500 testing sets.  Number of rounds can vary depending on what I'm doing, on my current training case, the training error seems to converge too quickly (under 20 epochs). However, I have noticed this non-variance at other times when the error will decrease over a period of 1000 epochs.  I have also adjusted the learning rate and momentum for the regular propagation.  Resilient propagation does not use a learning rate or momentum for updates.  This is being implemented using Encog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dataset seems problematic to begin with. 20 outputs for 4 inputs seem too many. The number of output is generally much smaller than the number of inputs. Most probably, either the dataset is wrongly formulated, or you have misunderstood something in the problem you are trying to solve. Anyway, some things regarding your other comments:

First of all, you don't use 1500 training sets, but one set with 1500 training patterns. The same goes for validation and testing.

Second, the output can't be **exactly** the same on each run, since the weights are initialized randomly and the outputs depend on them. However, **we want them** to be similar on each run. If they weren't it would mean that they depend too much on the random initialization, so the network wouldn't work well.

In your case, the highest output is the selected category, so if the same output is the highest every time your network is working well.

Comment: I have since changed my network to output one of two possible values.  I felt like having 20 outputs would somehow be easier for the machine to classify, but that's silly because dividing an area by 20 instead of 2 makes each target harder to hit accurately and reliably instead of easier.  Unfortunately, I'm now receiving a 50/50 hit rate.  There is an awful lot of noise, so I guess that will be my next step...  (continued)

Comment: ... But before I check your answer, can you tell me if having a dataset with 1500 _patterns_ that outputs nearly the same answer each time is a result of having a biased training set or one that is too saturated with a specific ideal? If the answer is 'could be anything', then a most likely culprit will do better than nothing.

Comment: When you have bad results, you can't know in advance if it is the dataset's or the algorithm's fault. That is why in every publication you see some well known datasets used for comparisons. If you are just starting out with neural networks, try the Iris & Wisconsin datasets from the UCI Repository. Your algorithm should have over 90% success in these. If not, there is probably some problem with the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If the network output is almost the same for different input patterns, the network is unable to categorize input well.

You say your network has 4 input nodes and 20 output nodes (right?). So there are 2*2*2*2 = 16 different possible input patterns. Why the hell you need 800 validation sets?

Your training data may be corrupt.

Comment: Please excuse any false assumptions that I make - I am still new to ANNs. This was originally a regression network which attempted to output a particular value.  This wasn't working too well so I thought I would try to have it classify the movement into one of 20 that I am interested in seeing. I see your point about the 2^4 possible answers, but the inputs are magnitudes not 1/0.  However, the output is either 1/0.  The 800 validation sets is based on a straight 70/10/20 split of the available data (ratios which I have tried adjusting). This data is based on previously known (hard) data.